# Did not find var/www diectory in ubuntu

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I installed apache2.It works when I go to localhost in browsers but I did not find any www folder in var folder.What is wrong with the installation?

Comment: `sudo find / -name www -type d`

Comment: ok I did it shows 
/host/wamp/www
/var/www .But when I go the respective directory i did not find it.I tried cd /var/www also but it shows No such file or directory.

Comment: you can just copy your files into those 2 directories by using `sudo cp`. You just mentioned `/var/www` exists in your system.

Comment: Ya.I got.can You please tell me the full command to place the php file there.thanks.

Comment: `sudo cp index.php /var/www/`. To copy a directory, `sudo cp -r MyFolder /var/www/`.